# What's the proper way to have a Thread-Unsafe object in a singleton?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, thread-safety

Let's say we have a NSMutableArray for example on a singleton object. The singleton object can obviously be called from multiple different threads.

Let's say we need users of the singleton to be able to addObjects or removeObjects. Or perhaps we have a custom object that we need to both set and read.

What's the proper way to handle these cases? Should every thread-unsafe property on a singleton have it's own serial/concurrent queue, and then overwrite addObject and removeObject functions for the NSMutableArray, wrapping reads in dispatch_sync, and writes in either dispatch_async(to a serial queue) or dispatch_barrier_async(to a concurrent queue)?

1) Does every thread-unsafe property need its own queue? Or should it at least have one in terms of performance. If multiple properties shared the same queue, it would be slower than necessary.

2) In what cases is this thread protection unnecessary. Ever? Or should thread-unsafe properties always have their setters and getter overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Does every thread-unsafe property need its own queue? Or should it
>   at least have one in terms of performance. If multiple properties
>   shared the same queue, it would be slower than necessary.

Depends entirely on how frequently you are pounding on the serialized APIs.   Start with a simple model and then move to more complex if needed.

And keep in mind that the implementation isn't necessarily limited to just adding queues at whim.

You could also use a multiple-reader, one writer model.   That would involve keeping an `NSArray*` copy of the mutable array's contents that the readers can simultaneously hit.  If the mutable array's contents are changed, then you can (thread safety in mind) swap a new immutable copy of the mutable array for the existing `NSArray *` (could be done with an atomic `@property` or you could use a concurrent queue for all reads with a barrier for the swap operation).

Something like the above might make sense when either the array is relatively small (cheap copies) or there are many many times more reads than writes.

> 2) In what cases is this thread protection unnecessary. Ever? Or
>   should thread-unsafe properties always have their setters and getter
>   overwritten.

A mutable collection is always thread unsafe, even when operating in a "readonly" mode.   Only immutable collections are thread safe.

So, yes, you need to make sure you serialize any operation that would cause a thread unsafe action.

Comment: thanks. If I were to go with a barrier for the swap operation, what if I need to give public access to things like removeObject or addObject. Is it best practice to just write public function for them, and within them once again barrier their operations on the concurrent queue.

Comment: @chrisP You could combine the two models; use a concurrent queue to access a readonly copy of your array.  Then use barrier'd addobject/removeobject operations to both mutate the mutable collection *and* make an immutable copy that is subsequently available for concurrent read access.   A barrier based model isn't useful with a mutable backing store because mutable collections aren't thread safe in any role.

Comment: thanks again. Do you mind kindly explaining to me the last line of y our comment. "A barrier based model isn't useful with a mutable backing store because mutable collections aren't thread safe in any role." IFF I can guarantee that all my writes to the NSMutableArray are barrier_async to a concurrent queue, then can my reader not just be `__block NSArray *returnArray;`, `dispatch_sync(myConcurrentQueue, ^ { returnArray = [myMutableArray copy]; });`, `return returnArray;`. Would this not work? Or it would still work, but is not as efficient as the additional NSArray you've mentioned.

Comment: And if that would still work, but is not as efficient, do you mind explaining that as well. Thank you!

Comment: @chrisP You can't have multiple threads calling `copy` on the mutable collection.   Copying isn't thread safe, either.   (And if you have a ton of reads with few writes, then copying the array for each read is inefficient).

Comment: ...etc. If anyone goes and switches a barrier async to non barrier or anyone adds some mutable accessor without a barrier, we find ourselves in a terrible situation. So I will make sure to never do this. I'm just interested from a hypothetical perspective "IFF all writes/accessors to the mutable collection were barrier asyncs, you could technically be safe with a copy in a dispatch_sync mutable collection." Even tho it's not a thread safe function, because we can guarantee in this case everything is barrier, we would not run into any issues. Stupid question really, but humour me :)

Comment: @chrisP As long as you guarantee that all calls made on the mutable collection are fully thread exclusive (i.e. synchronous, one at a time), then you can construct it however you want.